# alarm for direct connect is showing insufficient data with terraform, how to fix that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I tried creating alarm for direct connect using this [link](https://medium.com/@pythonaugust/create-alarm-for-direct-connect-from-another-aws-account-7e3bb4c91680).

But it is showing insufficient data, so I tried creating manually from aws console and it is working.

So, did a side by side comparison and tried following changes in dimensions.

```
connection_id  -> ConnectionId 
    aws_account_id -> "Account ID",AccountID,AccountId
    region         --> kept and removed
```

Not fruitful, as getting same insufficient data.

Please suggest.

Comment: I generally create an alarm in the console, look at the namespace / dimension / whatever else, then put it into infrastructure as code. If you want help you'll need to provide more information, such as screenshots of the two alarms showing the details of what they're monitoring.

Comment: fields are same now, but getting insufficient data. And I used exact steps as in the link I shared in first line.

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly say what you're trying to achieve, in plain language. Also include screenshots. eg "I want to be alerted when DC is unavailable". You said "alarm" but on which metric? You are best to get it going in the console before Terraform.

Comment: all those details are in the link I shared in the question